# How can I mimic Java object level inheritance to make literal value present or absent?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, interpreter

I am writing an Interpreter by following [Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/). The code I obtain there is in Java, so I am trying to translate Java code into C++. Everything was going well until I stumbled onto this:

```
 Token(TokenType type, String lexeme, Object literal, int line) {
    this.type = type;
    this.lexeme = lexeme;
    this.literal = literal;
    this.line = line;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return type + " " + lexeme + " " + literal;
  }
}
```

This is how I translated it into C++. However, I am unable to determine how to assign `Object literal` in this case. Java has general inheritance whereby everything inherits from the `Object` class, whereas C++, has nothing like that. This is how the two overloads are defined for `addToken`.

```
  private void addToken(TokenType type) {
    addToken(type, null);
  }

  private void addToken(TokenType type, Object literal) {
    String text = source.substring(start, current);
    tokens.add(new Token(type, text, literal, line));
  }
```

Token.hpp:

```
class Token {
private:
    TokenType type;
    std::string lexeme;
    std::size_t col;
    std::size_t line;
    //Object literal;

public:
    Token(TokenType type, std::string lexeme, std::size_t col, std::size_t line);
    std::string to_string() const;
};
```

I am trying to figure out how to handle this situation without implementing `Object`-like inheritance.

I can make the `Token` class a template and use `optional` as a data member of literal. This works until I hit an object type, but I do not know how it will work if I do not pass the type or if I encounter an unknown type.

As seen here, there are two overloads for `addToken`, and the `literal` value `null` can be passed as well. I do not think I can omit the type if I make a template for my `Token` class.

Please recommend a workaround, especially if there is a known template specialization that could be used as a base for the needed solution.

Comment: I would image using a void* or std::any class to represent, well, any class or null. Have you thought of this, since all java objects are on the heap.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of using something like pointers, where It can be handled easily. But I think it will increase the complexity, is not it? I just want to keep it simple.

Comment: Create an interface and take an instance of it (or `unitque_ptr` of it).. `without implementing Object-like inheritance.` 1. Extract only properties that you need that object to have. 2. Create a class with only those properties (methods). 3. Use a pointer to that class.

Comment: Just create a `Literal` abstract class with suitable derived classes for string literals, numeric literals, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Apparently, this seems to be more viable option.